# How to override the Spring Boot default OAuthTokenEndpoint

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I've been working on securing a Restful Service using Spring Security Oauth.  I've been banging my head trying to secure the /oauth/token endpoint using SSL and only allowing for POST calls.

I'm using @EnableAuthorizationServer which states

> Convenience annotation for enabling an Authorization Server (i.e. an
>   AuthorizationEndpoint and a TokenEndpoint) in the current application
>   context, which must be a DispatcherServlet context. Many features of
>   the server can be customized using @Beans of type
>   AuthorizationServerConfigurer (e.g. by extending
>   AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter). The user is responsible for
>   securing the Authorization Endpoint (/oauth/authorize) using normal
>   Spring Security features (@EnableWebSecurity etc.), but the Token
>   Endpoint (/oauth/token) will be automatically secured using HTTP Basic
>   authentication on the client's credentials. Clients must be registered
>   by providing a ClientDetailsService through one or more
>   AuthorizationServerConfigurers.

Which is great, but I can't seem to override the token endpoint piece or enforce POST-only calls, like with the intercept-url xml syntax

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore()
    }

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient('testApp')
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .authorities('ROLE_CLIENT')
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password","refresh_token")
                .secret('secret')
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(7200)

    }
}
```

I secured my Resource server with

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;


    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                    .requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()
                .and()
                    .csrf()
                    .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/authorize"))
                    .disable()
                .headers()
                    .frameOptions().disable()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
    }
}
```

Is there a similar builder syntax for the Authorization Servers TokenEndpoint security that uses requiresChannel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own config using 
`org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration`

Since i'm using Spring boot I just autowired the SecurityProperties and added this line for the SSL on the Oauth endpoints

```java
if (this.security.isRequireSsl()) {
    http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
}
```

And for the POST requirement

> http
>                   .authorizeRequests()
>                   .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,tokenEndpointPath).fullyAuthenticated()
>                   .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,tokenEndpointPath).denyAll()

Afterwards removed the @EnableAuthorizationServer so it would use my config.

Comment: POST only is the default (since 2.0.7). I opened another issue for the secure channels thing: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/480